# I added additional parameter in fabcar smart contractexample in hyperledger fabic. which is showing this error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I get this error:

> org.hyperledger.fabric.gateway.GatewayRuntimeException:
>   org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.ServiceDiscoveryException: Failed to find any endorsers for chaincode fabcar.

See logs for details

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8dIH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have correct server names in fabric-samples\first-network\connection-org*.yaml and fabric-samples\first-network\connection-org*.json.

These files are generated based on ccp-template.yaml and ccp-template.json. So, give correct server names in these files and get the network UP. Default values in these files would be 'localhost', unless you want to have them on a different server for some reason.